# (anObject = [enumerator nextObject] returns reverse order of array objects

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsenumerator

I get a `json` response from my web-service,I log it and get in a proper order,
but when I start parsing the data in array using `NSEnumerator` and apply
id anObject;

```
while ((anObject = [enumerator nextObject]))
```

and log anObject,I get the array in exactly reverse order,does any one have idea about this or is their any workaround to use enumerator to get objects in correct order for parsing?
I have posted after having searched in this forum but their isnt any for ios for this topic.

thankx in advance.

Comment: What does your JSON look like and what are the log results?

Comment: When you say **"I log it"** do you mean the response or the array?  (Try logging the array if you're not already.)

Comment: My Json response is http://pastehtml.com/view/1k8uprz.txt ,then i do  NSEnumerator *enumerator = [responseArray objectEnumerator];
    id anObject;
    self.mutArray = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
    while ((anObject = [enumerator nextObject])) {            Item *item = [Item initWithDict:anObject];
        [self.mutArray addObject:item];
    } , in the  log responseArray i get the response in correct order but for log anObject its exactly reverse order and i thing its due to (anObject = [enumerator nextObject], if their any substitute for using objectEnumerator.

Comment: There must be something else going on since `objectEnumerator` works fine in general.  Can you use `NSLog(@"First object: %@", [responseArray objectAtIndex:0]);` immediately before the while loop and compare it to the log of the first `anObject` from inside the loop?

Answer (score -1):

How about `NSEnumerator *enumerator = [arr reverseObjectEnumerator];` ?